# Finding a vector tangent to sphere at some point and parallel to XY-plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Trying to write some camera code for a personal project and getting stuck on a reasonable way to calculate this. Say I have a unit sphere $S$ with mid-point $P$ and some arbitrary point $Q$ on the sphere. I now want to find a vector $u$ that is both tangent to $S$ at $Q$ and parallel to the XY-plane. In my mind there should be 2 vectors fulfilling these constraints, pointing away from each other and having a z-component of 0. $P$ and $Q$ are known.

Comment: What do you mean by mid-point? Do you mean center?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, precisely

Comment: You have the vector PQ, and you know that the vector(s) you are looking for are of the form (x,y,0) and perpendicular to PQ. Taking the inner product and set it to 0. You now have ax+by=0. That give you the relation between x and y. Assuming I understood what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If $S=(a,b,c)$ and $Q=(d,e,f)$, then you are after a non-zero horizontal vector $u$ which is orthogonal to$$\overrightarrow{PQ}=(d-a,e-b,f-c).$$If $\vec u=(x,y,0)$, then you want to have$$\left\langle\overrightarrow{PQ},\vec u\right\rangle=0\quad\text{or}\quad x(d-a)+y(e-b)=0.$$You can take, say, $y=a-d$ and $x=e-b$. Unless, of course, $a=d$ and $e=b$ (that is, unless $Q$ is the “North pole” or the “South pole” of $S$), in which case you can just take, say, $\vec u=(1,0,0)$.